# Cufon syntax for multiple elements/selectors?

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

I'm using Cufon to replace the font used for multiple elements. The syntax I have is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Cufon.replace('h1.elementClassName, h2.newElementClassName, div#confirmationElementClassNameAndMore, h5.otherClassBlaBlaBla');
</script>
```

Apparently, it needs to be all on 1 line, otherwise it just doesn't work. But it becomes difficult to read as I add more elements to the list.

I've also seen the syntax below somewhere, but I was not sure, if declaring the REPLACE multiple times would slow down the loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Cufon.replace('h1.elementClassName');
  Cufon.replace('h2.newElementClassName');
  Cufon.replace('div#confirmationElementClassNameAndMore');
  Cufon.replace('h5.otherClassBlaBlaBla');
</script>
```

Will it affect speed or is it safe to use.?

Or is there another syntax that helps with visibility.?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use cufon now, most of the browsers are able to render custom fonts using CSS only. Take a look here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator. Fontsquirrel can convert you font for all browsers and will generate CSS for you.

Answer (score 0):

Font-face is inconsistent across browsers - you have to tweak margins to get a consistent result. Some fonts, when in small size, may also render really wrong.

This is the syntax to select more than one element with Cufon:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3', {fontFamily: 'FontName'});
</script>
```